# GetThreadContext registers always return 0xCCCCCCCC

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, msdn

I am trying to utilize GetThreadContext to view what the current debug registers are set to. No matter what program I debug, it returns 0xCCCCCCCC. I am able to successfully set breakpoints ctx.Dr0 and then catch these breaks with a custom exception handler, but if I try to view the address stored at ctx.Dr0, it always appears as 0xCCCCCCCC. Why is that?

Thanks

```
    CONTEXT ctx;
    GetThreadContext(GetCurrentThread(),&ctx);
    cout << hex << ctx.Eip << endl;
```

EDIT**

I think I did not ask my question well enough, because at the time I did not realize the error in my thinking. I actually was trying to call GetThreadContext from within the thread which I wanted to get it's context. This doesn't work for obvious reasons. Instead I think CONTEXT ctx = {CONTEXT_FULL} works. The answer that was most helpful was Hans Passant comment below.

Comment: That's what happens when you don't check the return value of winapi functions for an error, you just don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: [0xCCCCCCCC is uninitialized memory](http://stackoverflow.com/q/370195/995714)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot get a valid context for a running thread. You need to suspend the thread you want to get the context for. So, trying to do it in a current thread is not going to work.  This is clearly stated in the [`GetThreadContext()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679362.aspx) documentation:

> **You cannot get a valid context for a running thread.** Use the SuspendThread function to suspend the thread before calling GetThreadContext.
>
> **If you call GetThreadContext for the current thread, the function returns successfully; however, the context returned is not valid.**

Comment: Aw, I was editing to put the link to the MSDN page myself... Well done, Remy ;)

Answer (score 3):

On 64-bit platforms you can use [RtlCaptureContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This isn't however available to 32-bit platforms, so there you need a different solution. A possible approach is to use assembly as described in this blog post [Walking the stack of the current thread](http://jpassing.com/2008/03/12/walking-the-stack-of-the-current-thread/).

```
CONTEXT Context;
ZeroMemory( &Context, sizeof( CONTEXT ) );
Context.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_CONTROL;

__asm
{
Label:
  mov [Context.Ebp], ebp;
  mov [Context.Esp], esp;
  mov eax, [Label];
  mov [Context.Eip], eax;
}
```